# Is there any way to check if strict mode is enforced?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, ecma262, strict-mode

Is there anyway to check if strict mode 'use strict' is enforced , and we want to execute different code for strict mode and other code for non-strict mode. 
Looking for function like `isStrictMode();//boolean`

Comment: You could use `(() => !this)()`, e.g., `(() => !this)() ? "strict" : "sloppy"`

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The fact that `this` inside a function called in the global context will not point to the global object can be used to detect strict mode:

```
var isStrict = (function() { return !this; })();
```

Demo:

```
> echo '"use strict"; var isStrict = (function() { return !this; })(); console.log(isStrict);' | node
true
> echo 'var isStrict = (function() { return !this; })(); console.log(isStrict);' | node
false
```

Comment: For clarification, the return statement is equivalent to `return this === undefined`, it's not comparing it to the global object, it's just checking if `this` exists.

Answer (score 39):

I prefer something that doesn't use exceptions and works in any context, not only global one:

```
var mode = (eval("var __temp = null"), (typeof __temp === "undefined")) ? 
    "strict": 
    "non-strict";
```

It uses the fact the in strict mode `eval` doesn't introduce a new variable into the outer context.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how bulletproof is this in 2015, now that ES6 is here?

Comment: I verify that it works in ES6 on latest chrome and nodejs.

Comment: Nice! Works in NodeJS 10 REPL with/without `--use_strict` flag.

Comment: Doesn't it affect the performance of an application, especially React one?

Comment: @ellockie I wouldn't do it on a tight rendering loop, but as one-off per module init, I don't think so. Anyhow, there might be better ways of doing this in 2023.

Answer (score 28):

```
function isStrictMode() {
    try{var o={p:1,p:2};}catch(E){return true;}
    return false;
}
```

Looks like you already got an answer. But I already wrote some code. So here

Comment: This is better than Mehdi's answer as it will work everywhere, not only in a global scope. Upped. :)

Comment: This results in a syntax error, which happens before the code runs, so it can't be caught...

Comment: This will not work in ES6 either as the check is removed to allow computed property names.

Comment: Why should there be an error thrown in strict mode?

Comment: @skerit Can you elaborate on your syntax error? I do not get one.

Comment: The spec and engines behavior have changed. Now this throws in old engines, but it does not throw in new engines. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617139/whats-the-purpose-of-allowing-duplicate-property-names

Answer (score 16):

Yep, `this` is `'undefined'` within a global method when you are in strict mode.

```
function isStrictMode() {
    return (typeof this == 'undefined');
}
```

Answer (score 12):

### Warning + universal solution

Many answers here declare a function to check for strict mode, but such a function will tell you nothing about the scope it was called from, only the scope in which it was declared!

```
function isStrict() { return !this; };

function test(){
  'use strict';
  console.log(isStrict()); // false
}
```

Same with cross-script-tag calls.

So whenever you need to check for strict mode, you need to write the entire check in that scope:

```
var isStrict = true;
eval("var isStrict = false");
```

Unlike the most upvoted answer, this check by Yaron works not only in the global scope.

Answer (score 5):

More elegant way: if "this" is object, convert it to true

```
"use strict"

var strict = ( function () { return !!!this } ) ()

if ( strict ) {
    console.log ( "strict mode enabled, strict is " + strict )
} else {
    console.log ( "strict mode not defined, strict is " + strict )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can take advantage of the fact that in strict mode, variables declared in `eval` are not exposed on the outer scope

```
function isStrict() {
    var x=true;
    eval("var x=false");
    return x;
}
```