# Firefox ignores "use strict" in console

Tags: javascript, firefox, strict-mode

Here is the code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

```
function f2(){
  "use strict"; // see strict mode
  return this;
}

console.log(f2());
```

f2 call in script works fine. But its call from console shows window object! What's wrong? Setting "javascript.options.strict" option doesn't help.

[image]

In Chrome everything works fine.

Comment: That's right, it looks like a bug. Interestingly launching a some bare index.html that includes your example.js will apply "use strict" displaying undefined like it should be instead of an archaic global object.

Answer (score 2):

If you really did execute the exact MDN snippet, it would be a bug, that must have been already fixed because I can't reproduce it.

However, one should note that if we refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10480227/720297) and try to execute the tests in separated statements in firefox console:

```
>> var isStrict = (function() { return !this; })(); console.log(isStrict);
false
>> "use strict"; var isStrict = (function() { return !this; })(); console.log(isStrict);
true
```

This proves that Firefox's Dev tools do take `"use strict"` into account. Now if we try one more:

```
>> "use strict";
"use strict"
>> var isStrict = (function() { return !this; })(); console.log(isStrict);
false
```

What changed here is that `"use strict"` was used in a separated prompt rather than on the same one, and it would seems that Firefox's dev tools reinitialize strict mode for each prompt. As a consequence if instead of 
using exactly the wording of MDN you tried something like

- issuing `"use strict"` on the first prompt,
- then declaring your function on the second line
- and finally displayed it on a third line as we can see on the screenshot,

...the output would have been normal regarding the fact that `"use strict"` is reset on each prompt.

NB: note that on the other hand, the following seems to be working:

```
>> "use strict"; function f3(){return this;}
"use strict"
>> console.log(f3())
undefined
```