# Difference between online compilers (https://playcode.io/, programiz, leetcode) vs browser in Javascript Output

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run this piece of code in browser and compiler and getting two different outputs. What could be the cause for this
`

```
'use strict';

var fName = 'Matilda';
 const jonas = {
     fName: 'jonas',
     year: 1991,
     greet: ()=> console.log(`Hey, ${this.fName}`),
 };

 jonas.greet();
```

`

Browser Output: Hey, Matilda

Compiler Output: Hey, undefined

I have tried running this code in several different compilers, and getting the same output. I was expecting a consistency in output between environments. I'll be glad if someone can give me a good theoretical explanation for the same.

Comment: Simply typing "use strict" into your console does not enable strict mode. Replace your `console.log` with `console.log(this)` to see the effect.

Answer (score 1):

The sites which embed your code generally do some preprocessing for security reasons. This results in `"use strict"` not being the first line in the script so strict mode isn't triggered.

Comment: Is this true, or is this backwards? AFAIK the behavior here is that strict mode is *not* being activated in the console, where `this` is actually `Window` inside the method. In the mentioned online REPLs, `this` is assigned to the nameless global object. When I use this method, Chrome's console reports `false` while the online REPL reports `true`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480108/is-there-any-way-to-check-if-strict-mode-is-enforced