# Is there any way to check if React strict mode is enforced in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I want to check whether React's strict mode is enforced in JavaScript, there are some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480108/is-there-any-way-to-check-if-strict-mode-is-enforced).

However, I can't get any of them to work when I translate them to TypeScript.

I've looked online for a TypeScript boolean method for checking if I'm in Strict mode, but can't find one. Can anyone help, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OLD ANSWER(INCORRECT):**

<del>Maybe you can just simply use a file in the same directory as the configuration file. And read the tsconfig using the built in fs module and parsing it using json parse.</del>

<del>Hope this helps.</del>

**NEW ANSWER:**

I know it's quite hacky but, off the top of my head, the only solution that I can think of is you should write your component in a `string` and use  `Bable.transform()` to transform it on the fly while the app is running. This way, you can now use the `String.prototype.includes()` function to search for the `React.StrictMode` `JSX` element.

Hope this will help you in your project, once again, I know it's quite hacky and not the best solution.

Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks Alvin. 

The tsconfig file would tell me whether TypeScript strict mode is on. However, what I'm interested in is React strict mode. I've edited my question title to make that clearer. 

I've tried reading index.tsx file and searching for the string 'React.StrictMode'. However, doing so produced the HTML of index.html instead of just giving me the TypeScript code! 

Given that strict mode runs useEffect twice, I'm surprised my question hasn't been answered previously. You don't want to be changing your code when you remove strict mode before going to production.

Comment: Ok  Sorry for the misunderstanding and confusion caused

Comment: I have edited it, so please take a look!

Comment: Thanks Alvin - and no problem at all. :)